# Scrapy and MySql: Storing Lists

Tags: python, mysql, database, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently working on a small project with Scrapy, in which I'm storing my scraped data into MySql. The issue is that my scraped data isn't 1 to 1. I have provided source code and images of MySql below.

**Issue: When sending the data to MySql, only the first value of each list value is being saved.**

## main()

```
import scrapy

from ..items import CsgoProjectItem

item = CsgoProjectItem()

class ListOfSkins(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "list_of_skins"
    start_urls = ['https://csgostash.com/']

def parse(self, response):

    main_li_dropdown = response.css('li.dropdown')

    for item_category in main_li_dropdown[:-1]:
        item_class = item_category.css('.dropdown-toggle::text').getall() # Get Class (Step 1/4)

        item['item_class'] = item_class

        if item_category.css('.dropdown-menu.navbar-dropdown-large a::text'):
            item_type = item_category.css('.dropdown-menu.navbar-dropdown-large a::text').getall() # Get Type (Step 2/4 a)

            item['item_type'] = item_type

        if item_category.css('.dropdown-menu.navbar-dropdown-small a::text'):
            item_type = item_category.css('.dropdown-menu.navbar-dropdown-small a::text').getall() # Get Type (Step 2/4 b)

            item['item_type'] = item_type

        yield item
```

## items()

```
import scrapy

class CsgoProjectItem(scrapy.Item):
    item_class = scrapy.Field()
    item_type = scrapy.Field()
```

## pipelines()

```
import mysql.connector
import os

class CsgoProjectPipeline:

    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = '...',
            user = '...',
            passwd = '...',
            database = '...'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item_list""")
        self.curr.execute("""CREATE TABLE item_list(
        class text,
        type text
        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item

    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""INSERT INTO item_list VALUES (%s,%s)""", (
            item['item_class'][0],
            item['item_type'][0]
        ))
        self.conn.commit()
```

## scraped results

[image]

## MySql results

[image]

Notice how MySql only saved the first value of each list. If anyone could provide instruction on how to resolve, I would appreciate it. I believe I have to create a loop of the {item_class} and then match them to the {item_type}, however I am unsure how to do this while using Scrapy.

Comment: in store_db function, you only insert the first element of `item`

Comment: @MikhailGenkin awesome it worked! I appreciate it. Do you have suggestions for seperating the data however, currently the entire list is inside one cell in MySql.

Comment: I thought this is what you wanted. You can add more columns to your table by changing create_table function, and parse the dictionary into these columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `store_db` function, you only insert the first element of `item`:

```
self.curr.execute("""INSERT INTO item_list VALUES (%s,%s)""", (
        item['item_class'][0],
        item['item_type'][0]
    ))
```

You need to insert the full list. You need to dump the whole dictionary into a string and insert this string into mysql column
. Try

```
self.curr.execute("""INSERT INTO item_list VALUES (%s,%s)""", (
        item['item_class'][0],
        json.dumps(item['item_type'])
    ))
```

Don't forget to install and import json package, that can convert dictionaries into strings.